# Every Two Element in A Coset

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

> For every $a,b \in G$, $a,b \in cH$ for some maximal subgroup $H$ of $G$ and
>   some $c \in G$.

For what groups is the following property true? I know its true for $\mathbb{Z_m} \times \mathbb{Z_n}$ but what about $S_n$ or $A_n$? For $n = 3,4$, I have verified that this is true but is this true generally?

Comment: The order of the quantifiers is unclear to me. Are you asking whether for every $a,b$ I can find a $c$ and an $H$ (possibly different for different $a,b$?)

Comment: @yohBS: yes, that is correct. Feel free to edit if you think a correction will clarify this question.

Comment: If H is the subgroup generated by a and b and c = e, isn't it true that $a,b \in H$?

Comment: @JonasGomes My thoughts exactly. This is why I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @JonasGomes  Ok this is a better formulation of the question. Obviously doing what Jonas said above works but then there is nothing to be asked...

Comment: As stated, I think the proposition is false. I'll come up with a counter-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a,b\in cH$ iff $aH=cH$ and $a^{-1}b\in H$.

So the proposition is true iff every element $g=a^{-1}b$ of $G$ is contained in a maximal subgroup of $G$. If $G$ is finite, that's true iff $G$ is not cyclic.

Comment: Thank You, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

If $a=b$ the question is the same as asking "Do every group have a maximal subgroup?" And some groups (like $\mathbb{Q}$) do not have this property.